# Spring rest Template Get Call does not return List

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, resttemplate

When I run testSuccessGetUsers unit test I get response as

```
"body" : [ {
    "counter" : null
  }, {
    "counter" : null
  }, {
    "counter" : null
  }, {
    "counter" : null
  } ],
  "statusCodeValue" : 200,
  "statusCode" : "OK"
}
```

I'm unable to understand why the counter object is returned as null? Can someone please help me? Thanks!

```
https://europe-west2-zenhomes-development-project.cloudfunctions.net/counters/
```

returns a list of counters

Below is the unit test case for resttemplate:

```
@Test
    public void testSuccessGetUsers() throws Exception{
        String Url = "https://europe-west2-zenhomes-development-project.cloudfunctions.net/counters/";
        //create headers
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        //set content type
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        //make an HTTP GET request with headers
        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        ResponseEntity<CounterList[]> actual = httpHandler.sendGet(Url, httpHeaders, null, CounterList[].class);

        //verify request succeed
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, actual.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(200, actual.getStatusCodeValue());
        assertNotNull(httpHeaders.getContentType());
        assertTrue(httpHeaders.getContentType().includes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
```

Below is the CounterList class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CounterList implements Serializable {
    private Counter counter;
}
```

Below is the counter class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Counter {
    private String id;
    private Village village;

}
```

Below is the village class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Village {
    private String id;
    private String name;

}
```

Comment: The WebService returns a List/Array of Counter, not CounterList, so it can't be serialized into that

Comment: @Turo It Worked!! Thank you for all the help and time. I have one more question what is the best way to write unit test cases for resttemplate in spring boot?